# Rails - Adding to an array in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I have a column, called "plan selection", of arrays in a table called "Current Plans" that I want to be able to add additional values to these arrays.

For Example: If the array is currently ["a", "b", "c"], I want to be able to add a fourth element, "d", to the array.

So far I have created a new action in my Current Plans controller:

```
def addplan
    p = CurrentPlan.find(12)
    p.plan_selection << "Test"
    p.save
    redirect_to:back
end
```

However, while the code doesn't break, it also doesn't do anything at all except redirect me back to the same page.

```
Started POST "/clients/1/quotes/36/current_plans/12/addplan" for 66.186.164.130 at 2015-07-23 17:03:43 +0000
Processing by CurrentPlansController#addplan as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"83OuJJLivjOCXgzoKkPnzqz8HBk=", "client_id"=>"1", "quote_id"=>"36", "current_plan_id"=>"12"}
  CurrentPlan Load (30.6ms)  SELECT  "current_plans".* FROM "current_plans"  WHERE "current_plans"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
   (30.5ms)  BEGIN
   (30.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://crossing-mmiller.c9.io/clients/1/quotes/36/current_plans/12/
Completed 302 Found in 240ms (ActiveRecord: 213.1ms)
```

Route:

```
resources :current_plans do
    collection { post :planselection }
    post :addplan
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Current Plans Schema:

```
create_table "current_plans", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "client_id"
    t.string   "client_name"
    t.string   "plan_name"
    t.integer  "plan_year"
    t.string   "classification"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "plan_number"
    t.date     "effective_date"
    t.string   "quote_name"
    t.string   "plan_selection", default: [], array: true
    t.integer  "quote_id"
    t.integer  "benefit_detail_id"
    t.float    "group_premium"
end
```

Current Plan Model:

```
class CurrentPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :quote
   belongs_to :client
end
```

Comment: Showing your CurrentPlan model and the schema of the current_plans table will help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: define in model `serialize :plan_selection, Array`

Comment: Try to replace `p.save` with `p.save!`. This will throw an error if saving does not succeed and may help with finding the problem.

Comment: boulder - I added the information you requested. @Sontya - I added what you suggested and I now have a new Action Controller error <code> :PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information. </code> Terminal output : <code> SQL (31.0ms)  UPDATE "current_plans" SET "plan_selection" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "current_plans"."id" = 12  [["plan_selection", "---\n- Gold PPO 1500 90/70\n- Gold PPO 1000 90/70\n- Gold AWH HNOnly 1500 90/60\n- Test\n"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-23 18:31:41.197886"]] </code>

Comment: btw...how do you format for code inline?

Comment: @panmari didn't work, unfortunately. I am still getting the same error since I added `serialize :plan_selection, Array` to my Current Plan model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@boulder was correct in that the field wasn't being marked as dirty but the solution that turned out to work was adding this line `p.plan_selection_will_change!` before pushing "Test" into the array.

Comment: This page has a lot of insight on the topic of Rails 4 and Postgres: [link](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-arrays-in-rails-with-postgresql/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the statement you're using doesn't mark the field as dirty so the record is not updated. This is a known problem with serialized fields in Rails. 
The solution is using a different syntax:

> p.plan_selection = p.plan_selection.push("Test")

By the way, the table field is an array, which Rails is already aware of by reading the schema so you don't need and should not flag it as serialized in the model.

Comment: Still isn't saving "Test" into the array. No errors but no changes either. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I posted another answer for visibility but your explanation was spot on as to why it wasn't working, however, I had to take a different route to solving the issue. Thank you for your help. I would up-vote you but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: No problem; happy to help. You are right about `p.plan_selection_will_change!` being the way to do it.